# Webresponse doesn't work through GSM connection

Tags: c#, gsm, httpwebresponse

I'm trying to send http request through GSM VPN tunnel. Below is part of code responsible for sending it. I've tested it using "clumsy", and it works fine up to 400-500ms. But after getting program into target system, all tries to send request ends with error ("catch" occurs, out in device doesn't change its state).
GSM link is at poor location (pings 80-400ms, incidental packet drops etc.), but i was expecting that at least one from many tries will end with success. What is wrong in my code?

Webexception status is: "Timeout"

Complete http link looks like:

> 192.168.1.100/outs.cgi?out0=0

Answer is (states of outs in device in plain text):

> 10000

```
        private int switch_kontroler(string adress, int outnr, int state)
    {
        int i = 0;
        if (this.checkBox1.Checked == true) //I have checbox "start GSM mode" in Form
            goto GSM; 
        else
            goto Test;
   GSM:  
        if (i<3)
        {
            goto Test;
        }
        else
            goto Koniec;
   Test:
        try
            {
                i++;
                label3.Text = "Próba przełączenia: "+i;
                this.Refresh();
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://" + adress + "/outs.cgi?out" + outnr + "=" + state);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.Timeout = 1000; //BTW. Why program works up to 500ms if timeout is set at 1000?
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                label3.Text = result.ToString();
                if (result[outnr] - '0' == state)
                    if (result[outnr] == '1')
                    {
                        label3.Text = "Załączono kamerę";
                        return 1; //info to the rest of program about succes (or not) of this method
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        label3.Text = "Wyłączono kamerę";
                        return 0;
                    }
                this.Refresh();
                response.Close();
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                label3.Text = "Przełączenie nieudane: " + e.Status;
                this.Refresh();
                if (this.checkBox1.Checked == true)
                    goto GSM;
                else
                    goto Koniec;
Koniec:
       return 2;
                ;
        }
```

Basically i'm on a "script kid" level in c# so if you can be that nice, provide maximally possible complete code, please ;-)

Comment: When `catch` occurs, what is the exception being thrown?

Comment: It ends with "Timeout" status. That's kinda strange, i've started windows ping along with one of tries and longest response time was 350ms (and no packet loss)

Comment: 350ms ping and how much longer to download the target webpage over GSM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. Thanks to DavidG

It looks that response travels much longer than ping (it's only few digits in plain text so i'm surprised). I've rised timeout to 10 seconds and it works fine.

Ad.: Finally timeout rised to 20 seconds, even 15 was creating a problem for much part of time (Oddly, if there is connection, I get answer in 2-3 seconds, but timeout must be set to value 10+)